# Python pyautogui.click is right clicking instead of left clicking

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I'm using python3 through Anaconda Jupyter Notebook on macOS Mojave 10.14.1.

When I use `pyautogui.click()` in my code, it right clicks instead of left clicking like it should.

Even if I add `pyautogui.click(button='left')`, it still right clicks.

The same happens if I use `pyautogui.mouseDown()`.

Any idea what's going wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: i think pyautogui will follow your mouse primary button setting, is your mouse primary button set to Right ? Try setting your mouse primary button to Left

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by declaring `button=2` in the arguments:

```
pyautogui.click(button=2)
```

Comment: According to [documentation](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/ec2ed567af0e392d4b924e9459da4c6b9f5a4292/pyautogui/__init__.py#L324) and [code](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/ec2ed567af0e392d4b924e9459da4c6b9f5a4292/pyautogui/__init__.py#L364), button 2 is the same as `'middle'`. Probably there's something wrong with [kCGMouseButtonLeft](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/ec2ed567af0e392d4b924e9459da4c6b9f5a4292/pyautogui/_pyautogui_osx.py#L379) constant from pyobjc's Quartz package.